# AZURE: Get IP Addresses of Worker Role instances

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Is there a way to get all the private IPs of the instances of a Worker Role?

---

EDIT:
I'm deploying a Java Application via a Startup Task (cmd script) that configures and starts my application server (Tomcat). I need the IP Addresses while I am running this script in order to modify a configuration file.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more your question! For example on what language/platform you want to get these IP Addresses. And where would the process requiring these IP Addresses be running - i.e. within the role itself, or outside of the deployment.

Comment: I edited my question. Please tell me if more information is needed.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at AzureRunme project (https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureRunMe) instead of inventing the wheel? You may also refer to couple of articles I have about it on my blog: http://blogs.staykov.net

Comment: I already have a project that lets me to run my application in Azure. I only need to get all the private IPs of the instances of the Worker Role because I have to specify them in a configuration file (JGroups). I want to use JGroups because I'm using Hibernate Search and I want to replicate the indexes for all my instances.

Comment: but you still don't answer the very important question: in what platform/language do you want to get these - PowerShell, Java, .NET. AzureRunMe does everything for you - configures all required settings, including IP Addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what exactly you mean by the "private IP", but if you have an [internal endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh881877.aspx) defined you can get the address of it using:

```cs
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["YourInternalEndpoint"].IPEndpoint.Address;
```

Comment: any endpoint (does not have to be Internal) will give you the private IP address. The question however is how to get all the IPs of all the instances, not only the current one.

Comment: Correct, I just assumed because he used the word "private" that maybe he was looking for an internal endpoint. I had no other context to go off of originally. :)